# Access apache server only particular users?

Tags: apache, web-services, xampp

I installed xamp server on my machine. I want to give access to some users in my LAN 
network.But now everyone can access it. I want to restrict it.
i tried

```
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Please give me suggestion